# Method overloading with collection types doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, overloading

Consider the following class with overloaded methods.

```
public final class TeaParty {
  private void travellerListed( Collection o) { 
    System.out.println("travellerListed(Collection<?>)"); 
  } 
  private void travellerListed( List s) { 
    System.out.println("travellerListed(List<Number>)"); 
  } 
  private void travellerListed( ArrayList i) { 
    System.out.println("travellerListed(ArrayList<Integer>)"); 
  }

  private void method(List t) { 
    travellerListed(t) ; 
  }

   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      TeaParty test = new TeaParty(); 
      test.method(new ArrayList ()); 
  } 
}
```

I'm expecting "travellerListed(ArrayList)" as output. But I get "travellerListed(Collection)". 
What cause for this unexpected overloading ?

Comment: Hint on terminology: those are not "generic" types (from a "generics" point of view, you are actually using **raw** types here; which ... should never be used in the first place). So, this is only about overloading, and which version the compiler picks. And if you look more closely ... you find that yes, you do overloading; but you are **never** calling an overloaded method here!

Comment: About generic types (which are not relevant in your question): Generic types are only used during compilation. At runtime generic types are not available (type erasure) so you cannot for instance have `void travellerListed(List<Number> value)` together with `void travellerListed(List<Integer> value)` because these signatures are identical at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the code you posted results in `"travellerListed(List<Number>)"`, since you are passing the `ArrayList` to `method`, whose argument type is a `List`, so for the call to `travellerListed` the compiler chooses `private void travellerListed( List s)`, since method overloading resolution is determined by the compile-time type of the arguments (which means `private void travellerListed( ArrayList i)` cannot be chosen), and a `List` is a more specific type than a `Collection` (which explains why `private void travellerListed( Collection o)` is not chosen).